Send images to Whatsapp in Python using the Cloud API
How to send an image to Whatsapp in Python using the Cloud API?
As far as I understood, the process is:

Upload an image to Meta, and get its ID
Send the image, indicating its uploaded ID

Sources:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#upload-media
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/messages
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/messages/image-messages/
Thus, code to UPLOAD the image (seems ok):
url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{config_WA['PHONE_NUMBER_ID']}/media"
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + config_WA['ACCESS_TOKEN']}
files = {
    'file': ('filename.jpeg', open('filename.jpeg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg', {'Expires': '0'}),
}
data = {
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "recipient_type": "individual", 
}

upload_media = requests.post(
    url, 
    data={
        'messaging_product' : 'whatsapp', 
        'type': 'image/png',
    },
    files=files,
    headers=headers
)

Code to retrieve the image, showing it is indeed there (seems ok):
# Open image uploaded
url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/{id}/'
#-H 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>'

image = requests.post(
    url, 
    headers=headers
)

response = requests.get(image.url, headers=headers) # get the file binary
# save the received file
print(response.content)

And then, code to SEND the image:
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/"+config_WA['PHONE_NUMBER_ID']+"/messages"
# Headers
headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+config_WA['ACCESS_TOKEN']
    }

data = {
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "to": "+5521972832146",
  "type": "image",
  "image": {
    "id" : id,
    "caption": "The best succulent ever?"
    
  }
}

send_media = requests.post(
    url, 
    data= data,
    headers=headers
)



It runs but I get a "Response [400]", and send_media.text returns:
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Param image must be a JSON object.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"A64oeOdpaY7e7WjoPChkcfz"}}


You can send a JSON object like that:
send_media = requests.post(
    url, 
    json=data,
    headers=headers
)

